# BigCommerce Stencil API truncate or limit amount of categories from {{#each categories}}

Tags: html, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I'm trying to figure out how to limit the amount of categories returned by an `{{#each categories}}` loop. Currently, there are about 50 categories in products, and for a side bar I'm only trying to display about 5.

Right now the loop is set up as:

```
{{#each categories}} 
<li><a href="{{url}}" class="some-class">{{name}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

**Note: BigCommerce Stencil API doesn't allow you to register custom helpers so that isn't an option. They do have a custom `{{#for}}` helper (See: [Custom Helper Documentation](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/custom-handlebars-helpers)) but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. **

Answer (score 0):

Try to use {{@index}} in each loop to limit the categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each categories}}
              {{#if @index '<' '4'}}
```

//output list item for first 4 items in list

```
              {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
```

This is assuming categories are sorted